# navigator.geolocation.clearWatch is not working - React Native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I want to stop the location request when the app is in background.

React-Native version 0.53.3

This is my code for starting the watch:

```
    this.setState.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) => {
        this.setState({ position: { longitude: lastPosition.coords.latitude, latitude: lastPosition.coords.longitude } });

        if (typeof this.state.geoQuery != "undefined") {

            if (this.state.gpsError == true) {
                this.setState({
                    gpsError: false
                })
            }

            this.state.geoQuery.updateCriteria({
                center: [lastPosition.coords.longitude, lastPosition.coords.latitude],
                radius: 1500
            });

        }
    },
        (error) => this.setState({ gpsError: true }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1 });
```

This is where I want to clear the watch:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.state.watchID);
}
```

The ID I'm getting is always 0,

I have to force close the APP to stop the location, this translates in lot of battery usage if the user don't force close the APP.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, but I had this problem also in v. 0.66
My problem was that i used `useState` to set the ID which was then somehow translated into `false` which is not an ID ofcause..

so the solution was for me to set it back to 0....

```
if(!ID) { 
    ID = 0 
}
Geolocation.clearWatch(ID)
```